# Microsoft Office 365 users on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, office365

One of my client requirement is to show all office 365 users on WordPress site.
Is it possible ?

If possible so how i can achieve this. If i need to use API so how i can use.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 subscriptions are backed by Azure AD directories, thus, you can access the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). There are instructions on how to use the API in the documentation, if you have a more specific question about implementation ask again using the `azure-active-directory` tag.

If you are new to APIs, there are plenty of introductions and tutorials available, [here's one](https://gigaom.com/2010/10/29/using-apis-not-quite-as-hard-as-it-looks/).